# Appending fetched ejs items

Tags: javascript, express, append, ejs, fetch-api

**Objective:**
I have a button that runs a function to load more items from my Mongoose DataBase and add them to a table row. I use get to get and return data from my server side. And am following pointers from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55592727/11243236), but I am still unable to render what I need.

**Client side code:**

```
<main role="main">
<div class="container-fluid ">
  <div class="card-columns" id="test" value="<%=deals%>">
    <tbody>
      <tr id="content"><% include partials/row.html %></tr>
    </tbody>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container" style="max-width: 25rem; text-align: center;">
  <a id="8-reload" class="btn more" onclick="loadMore(8)"></a>
</div>

<script >
  const loadMore = async function(x){
    const response = await fetch(`/${x}`);

    if (!response.ok)
      throw oops;
    const data =await response.text();
    console.log(data);
    console.log($("#content"));
    await document.getElementById('content').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',data);

}
</script>
```

**Server JS request:**

```
app.get(`/:count`, (req, res) => {
  const count = parseInt(req.params.count);
  database.find({}, (err, found) => {
    if (!err){
      res.render("more",{items:found},(err,html)=>{
        if(!err){
          res.send(html);
        }else{
          console.log(err);
        }
      });    
    } else {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }).skip(count).limit(25);
});
```

when running the function nothing happens and browser console log reads the long string of html. and this for the place I want to append to:

jQuery.fn.init {}
**proto**: Object(0)

No errors on server console log. What am I missing?

**UPDATE** I tried Appending instead of to content to test and lo and behold I AM appending html, just not all of my content. int only inserts the opening and closing  of the entire html template none of the content between it. Weird.

Comment: What's in your response HTML? If it's not a collection of `<td>` elements, you're going to have trouble rendering it inside a `<tr>`

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Okay looks like the big problem was two things. The first issue was I was appending to a place that the content couldn't append to. The second issue was My template started with Table rows with more content in them which would not allow other stuff to render. Once I moved my jquery to a parent id and removed the table rows everything came in fine!